# Jupyter Lab not opening on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Im using Ubuntu as my OS. I have been able to download and open anaconda-navigator through command line. but I can't open up Jupyter lab or jupyter notebook. it is giving me the following error.

```
Access to the file was denied
The file at file:///home/basant/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-6359-open.html is not readable. It may have been removed, moved or file permissions may be preventing access.
```

I tried changing permissions but it hasn't helped. uninstalled and re-installed everything. didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem after an Ubuntu upgrade. The problem was solved by two steps:

1. Generate a jupyter config file, from terminal type:

   ```
    jupyter notebook --generate-config
   ```
2. Then open the file, which is saved at /home/username/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py, append `c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False` and save. You can now start jupyter.

Comment: This worked for me under Ubuntu 21.04. Note that this file includes the line mentioned in the answer, but commented out and set to True. So it is also possible to activate that line and set it to False instead of appending the line. Note, also, the explanation there under the heading "Disable launching browser by redirect file".

Answer (score 0):

I don't have sufficient reputation to add a comment, which would have been my preference, but found the answer above also resolved a similar issue on `Ubuntu 22.04` using `jupyter-lab`.  I am using Jupyter without Anaconda:

input: `jupyter-lab`

output: `Access to the file was denied`

`The file at .local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-42340-open.html is not readable.`
    `It may have been removed, moved, or file permissions may be preventing access.`

The file did not exist so changing permissions made no sense.